# Magnetization of a cylinder

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

Suppose we have a short circular cylinder of radius $a$ and length $L$ carrying a uniform frozen-in’ magnetization $\mathbf{M}$ parallel to its axis.

Why is there no bound surface current on the two sides of the cylinder?

I understand that for a long circular cylinder, due to it being infinite, the direction of the magentic field is  $\hat{\boldsymbol{\phi}}$ direction.

[image: 1]

This is regarding Problem 6.9 from *Introduction to Electrodynamics* by Griffiths where we need to find the magentic field due to polarization.

In the answers when finding the bound current it says

> [image: 2]

Comment: hint: make a small rectangular loop whose "short" sides are parallel with and the "long" sides are perpendicular to $M$, resp.,; now calculate the circulation.

Answer (score 1):

There is a surface current resulting from the magnetisation, but using it to find the field is an alternative to using M. It's a choice between a macroscopic continuum description or a more microscopic charges and currents description. The same choice arises at the surface of a polarised dielectric, where there is a E discontinuity.